# Entity Framework Code First: Production Env - Id cannot be null

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core

When I run my app in development (via VS), I can add users to my local DB just fine. But after publishing my app, and creating a cloud-based DB, I get the following error when trying to create a new user:

> Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'Id', table 'MyDb.dbo.Users'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.

I copied the content of my local database to the cloud-based DB via SQL Server Management Studio.

Is there some sort of inconsistency between EF and my production DB? I tried setting the Default Connection to the clould DB (in both Prod and Dev appsettings.json) then running `update-database` but it says that the DB is up to date.

I wouldn't suspect that I would need to explicily add the attributes `[key]` and/or `[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]` in production when I don't have to do so in the development env... would I?

#### User Model

```
public class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Username { get; set; }

    ...
}
```

#### Update

Upon further inspection, the production DB does not show the ID column as a PK. None of the tables in the DB recognize columns that should be PKs and FKs. Obviously there's a disconnect between EF and the production environment... but I still don't know how to fix it?

Comment: I'd compare dev and production User table Id column whether dev has an identity increment enabled.

Comment: There's the issue... in my production DB, none of the tables have keys... but why? Shouldn't that data be copied over when you do an Export in SSMS?

Comment: Also, I did `add-migration` just so I would have a migration to add to the prod DB, then I did `update-database`. It updated but that still didn't change that the prod DB doesn't show PKs and FKs...?

Comment: What did you do exactly to get your database in production? Recount the steps, because something went off there. As far as migrations go, EF doesn't migrate keys. If you were to remove the column and then add it back, it should add it as a PK, but it won't make an existing column a PK.

Comment: Yep, I haven't tested it yet (I'm on lunch, Lol) but my thought is this: I used SSMS's data export wizard, and that didn't identify columns as keys. Then when I did Update-Database, it saw the columns as present, and did nothing with them. My plan: Delete all tables from Prod DB, run Update-Database, then use SSMS to copy the entries from Dev to Prod. I'll let you know how that goes..

Comment: _I copied the content of my local database to the cloud-based DB via SQL Server Management Studio_ don't do that, let EF create the database. some EF Core providers act differently depending on which database version is used (i.e. Pomelo MySQL Provider does that depending on if target is i.e. 5.5 or 5.7)

Comment: I'm not certain that you get PK/FK out of SSMS* unless you use "generate scripts" and even then it's one of the (many) options you have to select (*not counting doing a backup/restore of course). But you said it yourself, you used the **data** export wizard, I'd not expect keys/constraints/indexes to come along (though perhaps in mistaken, it's been a while since I've used that specific tool in SSMS)

Comment: I deleted the database, then recreated and left it empty. then used EF `update-database` to create it. The correct columns were identified as PK/FK. I did, however, then have trouble copying data from the local db to the cloud-based db. Since my db is practically empty at this point, I just recreated the data.

Comment: @pinkfloydx33, you are correct that you need to use "generate scripts" to get the keys. I toyed with going that route rather than using EF as well.